# Working with MySql database in C#/ Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Hello, I'm currently working on a project which contains a part in which you have to simply import data from database in different ways. My database is hosted on a local MySql server under localhost.

I want to know the most flexible and easy way to execute queries on my MySql database (of course in C# code). I've tried using string interpolation ($"" syntax) for modifying text of the query but I think it is not the best way to do this.
(its getting very complicated when you want to apply some more complex query)

Comment: Have you tried entity framework?

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_username=@val1 AND admin_password=@val2", MySqlConn.conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", "admin");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", "pass");
cmd.Prepare();
MySqlDataReader res = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ;)